# Angular2 can you subscribe for more than one parameter from same json?

Tags: angular, http, typescript, subscribe

So is it possible to subscribe to more than one json variables?

```
 this.http.get(this.api_url + "preference")
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(res => this.limit = res.limit, res => this.sources = res.sources);
```

In this example, the sources is an array of strings. 
If you do it like this, only limit will be set.

my json:

```
{   "sources":["examplePage"],
    "limit":5
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do multiple operations in the subscribe body by using curly braces `{}` to define the body of the function and then assign the two variables like so:

```js
this.http.get(this.api_url + "preference")
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(res => {
        this.limit = res.limit;
        this.sources = res.sources;
});
```

As an aside the way subscribe is written in your question the `limit` will be set when the http request succeeds and the sources will be set when the request fails. `subscribe(/* success */, /* error */, /* finished */)`